# Mocking global functions in Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm testing some functions with Jest and have the following:

`functions.ts`:

```js
export function processEvent = () => {
    return (event: IEventData) => {
        ...
        const eventType = getEventType(event);
        ...
    }
}

export function getEventType(event: IEventData): string {
    ...
}
```

`functions.test.ts`:

```js
import * as Functions from './functions.ts';

describe('processEvent', () => {
    let processor: (event: IEventData) => {};
    let getEventTypeSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
    let event: IEventData;

    beforeEach(() => {
        processor = Functions.processEvent();
        getEventTypeSpy = jest.spyOn(Functions, 'getEventType');
        event = <IEventData>{};
    });

    it('should ...', () => {
        getEventTypeSpy.mockreturnValueOnce(...);
        ...
    });
}
```

`functions.ts` has no namespace specified, so it's just sitting in global. When I step through the `spec.ts` file, the `getEventTypeSpy` was created properly, but as soon as it steps into `functions.ts` from the test, the function has the mock fields removed and just calls its actual implementation. I know that throwing a namespace around all the functions in `functions.ts` will resolve the issue, but that is not an option. How do I mock `getEventType()`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, `export` keyword belongs to ES6, after babel compile and transform them to es5, the function(`getEventType`) name will be changed. That's why `jest.spyOn` failed. Here is the unit test solution:

`functions.ts`:

```js
export interface IEventData {}

export function processEvent() {
  return (event: IEventData) => {
    const eventType = exports.getEventType(event);
    return eventType;
  };
}

function getEventType(event: IEventData): string {
  return '';
}

exports.getEventType = getEventType;
```

`functions.test.ts`:

```js
import * as Functions from './functions';
import { IEventData } from './functions';

describe('processEvent', () => {
  let processor: (event: IEventData) => {};
  let getEventTypeSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
  let event: IEventData;

  beforeEach(() => {
    processor = Functions.processEvent();
    getEventTypeSpy = jest.spyOn(Functions as any, 'getEventType');
    event = {} as IEventData;
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should pass', () => {
    getEventTypeSpy.mockReturnValueOnce('message');
    const actual = processor(event);
    expect(actual).toBe('message');
    expect(getEventTypeSpy).toBeCalledWith(event);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59311270/functions.test.ts (12.949s)
  processEvent
    ✓ should pass (8ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |    83.33 |      100 |    66.67 |    83.33 |                   |
 functions.ts |    83.33 |      100 |    66.67 |    83.33 |                11 |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.997s, estimated 17s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59311270